# Salesforce Subscription management

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to set up salesforce subscription management in org where it's turned on.

Found this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TI4V9vSzf4
and this article
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/revenue/subscription-management/guide/set-up.html (somehow helpful)

So I followed the step to set up my org, created product and that is where it ends. Cannot configure Product Selling Model Options
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIEnD.png)

Do you have similar issue? Could you suggest some helpful articles, documentation, videos etc.?

Thank youuuu